# How to install RtidyHTML on Mac?

Tags: r, html-parsing, package

Any ideas how I can install RTidyHTML when I get the following error message?

```
install.packages("RTidyHTML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
trying URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/RTidyHTML_0.2-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 554953 bytes (541 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 541 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RTidyHTML’ ...
./configure: line 3: make: command not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RTidyHTML’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library/RTidyHTML’
```

Comment: Looks like the source is from March 2010 which makes me think it may not build correctly on 2.13. Also, do you have the appropriate tool chain (http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/) needed to build R packages?

Comment: That might be it, although I believe that I´m also missing the make command.... Anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Just a comment... With the latest XCode 4, you'll often need to specify a target architecture other than ppc which is no longer supported. This applies for R, Python, and many other software. It has been discussed elsewhere on this site, but generally something like `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" {your stuff here}`will work for code compiled in the Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install XCode on your Mac if you want to compile from source. (Roman's comment only applies to Windows machines.) I just tried installing it on an XCode-equipped Mac running R 2.13.0 and get first a warning during compliation

```
ld warning: in libtidy/libtidy.a, file is not of required architecture
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library/RTidyHTML/libs/x86_64
```

... and then get an error during the test load that is part of the install script:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library/RTidyHTML/libs/x86_64/RTidyHTML.so': 
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library/RTidyHTML/libs/x86_64/RTidyHTML.so, 6): Symbol not found: _tidyBufFree
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library/RTidyHTML/libs/x86_64/RTidyHTML.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I suppose it is possible that it may compile under a 32 bit version of R on the Mac.64-bit. See [Simon Urbanek's web page:](http://r.research.att.com/) for more specifics and some installers for other packages.

EDIT: Installation while running  32bit R from the GUI was successful with a current R (version 2.13.1 RC (2011-07-03 r56263) )

Comment: OK. Just installed XCode and installed from source as detailed above. Seems to work fine. Thx for the Xcode input...

Comment: @Misha: Which OS and versions?

Comment: *DWin: Mac OS X 10.6.8, R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13), x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0